# Share video to WhatsApp and other apps using Android Intent (Java)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, share-intent, content-values

I want to implement share video to whatsApp and other app feature using Android Intent system.
I have been looking for it for last 2 days but I did not get proper solution and some solutions I found on StackOverFlow, they no longer work I guess.

**Whenever share Intent opens and I click on whatsApp and choose contact to share then it says file format is not supported**

Below is my code:

```
ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
                        content.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                                System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
                        content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
                        content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, "/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20210822-WA0002.mp4");
                        ContentResolver resolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
                        Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);

                        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Title");
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"share:"));
```

Comment: First, use a concrete MIME type with `ACTION_SEND`. Second, you do not have rights to access that content on Android 11+.

Comment: Hey @CommonsWare, can you tell me what is mean by concrete MIME type?

Comment: `video/*` is a wildcard MIME type. Do not use that when you are the *supplier* of content. Use a concrete MIME type, like `video/mp4`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did changes as you said and I tested app on Android 8, 10.
Still it says "This file format is not supported"
Now I really do not have any idea what to do, I have been searching for it from last 3 days.